# My stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 when is execute with JOB its fails, but without its working great

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure wich its like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_ALIMENTATION_VolumeVentes]
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT EDS, NomEDS,AgenceEDS, AgenceNomEDS,SecteurEDS, SecteurNomEDS,DirectionEDS,DirectionNomEDS,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM CPListeVentesNonConformes WHERE CPListeVentesNonConformes.EDS = CPRT.EDS AND TypePart='PP') AS ListeVenteNC_PP,
             (SELECT count(*) FROM CEListeVentesNonConformes WHERE CEListeVentesNonConformes.EDS = CPRT.EDS AND TypePart='ET') AS ListeVenteNC_ET,
             (SELECT count(*) FROM CPListeVentesNonConformes WHERE CPListeVentesNonConformes.EDS = CPRT.EDS AND TypePart='PP' OR TypePart='ET') AS ListeVenteNC_PPET,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM  ListeVentes WHERE IDES01 = CPRT.EDS AND TypePart='PP') AS ListeVentes
    INTO VolumeVentes
    FROM CPR CPRT
    GROUP BY EDS, NomEDS,AgenceEDS, AgenceNomEDS,SecteurEDS, SecteurNomEDS,DirectionEDS,DirectionNomEDS,TypePart

END
```

When i execute with the command line **EXEC [dbo].[P_ALIMENTATION_VolumeVentes]**
that work super great my table is create.

But when i use SQL Agent to schedule a job i have a nice surprise to have this error :

> Executed as user: ZRES\CSAPREP10IUCRADM. The conversion of a varchar
>   data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   [SQLSTATE 22007] (Error 242)  The statement has been terminated.
>   [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.

The structure table who will be create VolumetVentes have **no fields with a type as datetime**

Here is the structure of the table[VolumeVentes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoREd.png)

I don't understand exactly where is the error ?

Thank you for help

Comment: Can you confirm the job is executing `EXEC [dbo].[P_ALIMENTATION_VolumeVentes]`

Comment: could you provide table definitions for tables CPR, CPListeVentesNonConformes, CEListeVentesNonConformes and ListeVentes?

Comment: Can you script your job and post the job step that is failing? It sounds like the job is doing something other than just running this stored procedure.

Comment: Are any of the columns mentioned in `ListeVentes` or `CPListeVentesNonConformes` or CEListeVentesNonConformes` a datetime data type?  If the `TypePart`, `EDS`, or `IDES01` are datetimes, the comparison to your other columns would fail.

Comment: The job is execute with this command EXEC [dbo].[P_ALIMENTATION_VolumeVentes]

Comment: I had been resolve by setting the language SET LANGUAGE French;

Answer (score 2):

Actually it should never work since you already have `VolumeVente` table.

`SELECT INTO` creates new table with columns described in select statement
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029(v=sql.120).aspx

You should modify this code to become `INSERT SELECT`.

But you will probably still get the same conversion error because (I guess) column order is not correct in select statment and does not match column order in existing table. That is why you should always explicitly define column list in `INSERT INTO` clause, so the final script will look like:

```
INSERT INTO VolumeVentes(EDS, NomEDS,AgenceEDS, AgenceNomEDS,SecteurEDS, ...)
SELECT EDS, NomEDS,AgenceEDS, AgenceNomEDS,SecteurEDS
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
INSERT INTO... Statement
```

instead of

```
SELECT INTO FROM... Statement
```